# how to add a logo on custom wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a WordPress theme from scratch at the moment and I seem to be stuck on trying to add a logo to the top left corner of the page where you would normally see the title of the page.

```
<h1>
  <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a
</h1>
<div class="site-description">
    <h3>
        <?php echo html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('description')); ?>
    </h3>
</div>`
```

So instead of the h1 tag there, I would like an image that will allow the user to return to the homepage. Also would I need to save the image in a specific folder ?

Please help and thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.jpg" />
<div class="site-description">
    <h3>
        <?php echo html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('description')); ?>
    </h3>
</div>
```

assuming that image is in the images folder of template directory with file name logo.jpg

Comment: Hey Ajay, just tried that however still showing me a broken image. The directory for my images is as followed "/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/CVTheme2015/images" and then the image is called logo.jpg

Comment: check the updated one

Comment: Hey Ajay, 
Thank you so much bro ! Works well ! 
Did it not work the first time round because we had template_directory uri ?

Answer (score 0):

Use
`<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
  <img src="image.jpg" width="32" height="32">
 </a>`

instead of

`<h1>
  <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a
</h1>`

Working well for me

**See the image** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs23W.jpg

Comment: Hey Ian thanks for the help but that didn't work for me kept on giving me a broken image link but thanks all the same for your help !